# iOS Enterprise Distribution:How does apple limit no of devices

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ios-provisioning

Considering the general iOS Enterprise distribution program guidelines it is mentioned that the number of devices i can distribute it to is  limited to 100.

I am using Dropbox to distributemy app. Now how does apple keep a tab on the number of devices the app has been distributed/installed on and limit it to 100 ?
Because so far i can download it on any device and i am not registering my device anywhere, so how is this count maintained? Or is my understanding not correct in this direction??

Comment: iOS Enterprise is not limited to 100 devices.

Comment: You are conflating two situations. With a Development cert/prov profile you can only deploy to 100 devices. Using the Enterprise cert/prov profile you can install on infinite devices.

Comment: I am confused between 3 situations , i.e which profile is going to be used where
1) App store Distribution
2) Ad hoc distribution i .e Via dropbox etc
3)installing on devices for unit testing .